# How to reset the values of `data` `isLoading` and `error` returned from hook in RTK query in a react typescript application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to `query` data from an end point with different params based on button click event.

I used the code splitting method by rtk query and created the base service as

```js
import { createApi } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
import { axiosBaseQuery } from "./util";

export const appApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: axiosBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: `https://baseurl`,
  }),
  refetchOnReconnect: true,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

and inject endpoint like

```js
import { appApi } from "./appApi";

export const popupAPI = appApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPopupData: builder.query<
      any,
      {
        id: string;
        startDate: string | Date | null;
        endDate: string | Date | null;
      }
    >({
      query: (params) => {
        const { id, startDate, endDate } = params;
        return {
          url: `kpi/?id=${id}&startdate=${startDate}&enddate=${endDate}`,
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
  overrideExisting: true,
});

export const { useGetPopupDataQuery } = popupAPI;
```

In the component file the `start date` is set initially and changes on button click.

```js
const startDate = moment()
  .subtract(selectedDays || 1, "days")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const endDate = moment()
  .subtract(1, "days")
  .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

The `selectedDays` is initially set to `1` and changes to 2, 3, etc on button click. I subscribe to the data and other variables like

```js
const {
  data,
  isLoading,
  error,
} = useGetPopupDataQuery({
  id
  startDate: startDate,
  endDate: endDate,
});
```

On the first time, when component mounts the values of `isLoading`, `data` and `error` are set accordingly and when the data fetch completed the `isLoading` is set to false and `data` with data. But the issue is when I click the button the `selectedDays` changes and an API call is send. But the previous `data` `isLoading` `error` are not changed/reset. So I'm not able to show the loading/intermediate stage. The after the data fetch completes when inspected the `data` variable is filled with new data. I'm trying to resolve this issue and any help/suggestions would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `isLoading` flag is used when the query is being initially made and there are no previous requests cached in the store. You might be looking to use the `isFetching` flag instead of, or in addition to, `isLoading`. The `data` will simply be the cached data from the previous successful request.

See [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery)

> ```
> type UseQueryResult<T> = {
>   // Base query state
>   ...
>
>   // Derived request status booleans
>   isUninitialized: boolean // Query has not started yet.
>   isLoading: boolean // Query is currently loading for the first time. No data yet.
>   isFetching: boolean // Query is currently fetching, but might have data from an earlier request.
>   isSuccess: boolean // Query has data from a successful load.
>   isError: boolean // Query is currently in an "error" state.
>
>   refetch: () => void // A function to force refetch the query
> }
> ```

Here's an example I use for handling subsequent requests.

```js
const {
  data,
  isLoading as popupDataIsLoading,
  isFetching as pPopupDataIsFetching,
  error,
} = useGetPopupDataQuery({
  id
  startDate: startDate,
  endDate: endDate,
});

const isLoading = popupDataIsLoading || pPopupDataIsFetching;
```

Here you can apply any conditional logic when the query is either being loaded for the first time ***or*** an active request is pending.

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you are looking for a "nuclear" option then there also exists [`resetApiState`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#resetapistate).

> Signature
>
> ```
> const resetApiState = () => ({
>   type: string,
>   payload: undefined,
> })
> ```
>
> Description A Redux action creator that can be dispatched to manually
> reset the api state completely. This will immediately remove all
> existing cache entries, and all queries will be considered
> 'uninitialized'.
>
> Note that hooks also track state in local component state and might
> not fully be reset by resetApiState.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> dispatch(api.util.resetApiState())
> ```

This resets the entire API state and may very likely be too blunt a tool though. Use with caution.